# Get a web page in Java Class

Tags: java, xml, client, htmlunit

I currently use the htmlunit library to get a web page with all the javascript and jsp loaded. 
htmlunit doesn't seem very poweful -- what alternatives exist?

Comment: htmlunit is afaik the most powerful one...especially regarding javascript...but you must spend some time and learn it

Comment: I get most error about load of javascript and infact when i use a jvisualvm i see that my class spend more time to catch these errors

Answer (score 3):

HtmlUnit is quite powerful if you have the time to learn it. If the time it takes to learn HtmlUnit is your obstacle (as it was mine), [JWebUnit](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin/index.html) might be a good option for you. It's based on HtmlUnit, but it's much easier to use and learn. It's been about a year since I used it, but it was exactly what I needed when I was still a Java newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Apache HTTP client and was pleased.

[Here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) is a link.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLUnit is afaik the only option for what people call "headless browser", and as I get it, this is the functionality you need. Just you to know (from my experience): sometimes result from htmlunit, and browsers are a bit different; but it depends on what you need (or how you use that result). Few times I got wrong dynamic element position, and there are two options:

1. I could change javascript, to get the same result for all major browsers and htmlunit
2. I had to add some css style, and javascript code, whcih does not influence page view I get in browser, but helps htmlunit to fix layout in right way.

And actually it is quite logical - no browser uses htmlunit as rendering engine :) And that's was the only problem with this library so far.